How to avoid disposing service after method finished or do it manually
I've been developing a web application with aspnet core and abp-framework
abp => 7.2.1
dotnet => net7.0
the problem is I have a method which is responsible for two job

do some process
log the result of that operation

the length of these jobs could be major so I decided to do it concurrently
Here is a breif of what service looks:
public class SomeAppService : ISomeAppService, ApplicationService
{
   private readonly IRepository<LogTable,int> _logTableRepository;
   public SomeAppService(IRepository<LogTable,int> logTableRepository)
   {
       _logTableRepository = logTableRepository;
   }
   public async Task<bool> CommitBulkOperation(int typeOfOperation)
   {
      List<Data> d = FetchSomeData();
      List<Task> aggregatedTasks = Enumerable.Range(0,11).Order().Select(x =>{
         List<Data> pagedData = PageData(x);
         return new Task(async () => await PerformOperationAndLogResult(pagedData));
      }).ToList();
      aggregatedTasks.ForEach(x => x.Start());
      await Task.WhenAll(aggregatedTasks);
      return true;
   }
   public async Task PerformOperationAndLogResult(List<Data> data)
   {
      foreach(var currentData in data)
      {
          var response = currentData.Type switch
         {
            1 => await Handler1(currentData);
            2 => await Handler2(currentData);
            _ => Throw new Exception();
         };
         await AddHistory(response);
      }
   }
   internal async Task AddHistory(LogTable logTable)
   {
      await _logTableRepository.InsertAsync(logTable);
   }
}

after Task.WhenAll excutes tasks going to complete their jobs in background but after the first triggered task comes to end and want to submit log this error appears

Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it (or one of its parent scopes) has already been disposed.

Is there any solution so I can fix this error?

The error is telling you you're probably using the wrong lifetime scope. What is it?

I didn't specified the life time so base on documentation it's scope
